# Can the Family Visitor visa be canceled because the settlement visa has been refused?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-cancellation, mozambican-citizens

I am a Mozambican married to a UK British citizen wife. I have been traveling back and forth on Family Visitor visa for a period of 7 years now. Just by the ends of 2014 I applied for a settlement visa which has been refused. Now, when I handed in the passport asking for the settlement visa I had Family Visitor visa already - even though they have refused to grant the settlement one. They did not cancel the Family Visitor one which would help me visit my family for two more months.

Can I travel go see my family and come back to Mozambique by the 9th March to reapply for the one that has been refused?

Won't they return me back at the airport?

Comment: I assume it's the end date of his family visitor's visa.

Comment: 9th March would be the end date of my family visitor's visa.

Answer (score 3):

You applied for a settlement visa whilst simultaneously holding a valid family visit visa.  Your settlement application was refused.  You want to know if they can cancel the family visit visa because of this.

Yes, they can cancel any visa any time they want.  In your case they did not cancel the visit visa when they refused your settlement application, so it remains valid.  When you next present your passport at a UK entry port, the Immigration Officer has the option to cancel or not.  He will generally cancel an entry clearance ONLY if it was obtained by fraud or a change in circumstances has occurred; so you should be prepared for a line of questioning on these topics.